# Comparing nested inner class by overloading operator C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm in the process of implementing a page replacement algorithm for a class and I'm running into an issue when comparing an inner class for one of these algorithms where my generic `Frames` class (similar to vector, but fixed in size) it not calling my overloaded `==` operator.

In `Algo.cpp`, I have a line:

```
 const bool contains = this->frames->contains(new scNode(data));
```

which calls the `contains` method from my `Frames` class:

```
bool contains(T data) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < this->_size; i++) {
        if(this->list[i] == data) { // not calling scNode == operator
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The issue I'm encountering is that my overloaded `==` operator defined in `Algo::scNode` is not being called in the `contains` method. I tried playing around with access modifiers, but no dice. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[Frames.h](http://hastebin.com/otipihijen.cpp)

Algo.h

```
#include "Page.h"
#include "Frames.h"

class Algo {

public:
    static Algo* get();
    void run(Page page);
    unsigned faults();

    class scNode {
    public:
        unsigned reference:1;
        int data;
        unsigned long _time;

        scNode(int data) {
            this->data = data;
            this->reference = 0;
            this->_time = (unsigned long) time(NULL);
        }

        bool operator==(const scNode &other) {
            return this->data == other.data;
        }
    };

private:
    static Algo* instance;

    Algo() {
        this->_faults = 0;
    }

    unsigned _faults;
    Page page;
    Frames<scNode*> *frames;

    /**
     * @return the index to remove from the Frame object.
     */
    int removeIndex();

};
```

Algo.cpp

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

#include "SecondChance.h"

SecondChance* SecondChance::instance = NULL;

SecondChance* SecondChance::get() {
    if(instance == NULL) {
        instance = new SecondChance();
    }

    return instance;
}

void SecondChance::run(Page page) {
    this->page = page;

    this->frames = new Frames<scNode*>(this->page.frames, NULL);

    unsigned index = 0;

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < this->page.pages.size(); i++) {
        const int data = this->page.pages[i];
        const bool contains = this->frames->contains(new scNode(data));
        scNode *node = this->frames->get(index);

        if(node == NULL && !contains) { // entry is empty
            std::cout << "Fault: " << data << "\r\n";
            SecondChance::_faults++;
            this->frames->add(new scNode(data));
            if(++index == 3) {
                index = 0;
            }
        } else if(contains) {
            if(node != NULL) {
                ~node->reference;
                node->_time = (unsigned long) time(NULL);
            } else {
                throw new std::runtime_error("Bad reference to node");
            }
        }
    }

    delete this->frames;
}

unsigned SecondChance::faults() {
    return this->_faults;
}

int SecondChance::removeIndex() {
    unsigned long min = ULONG_MAX;
    int minIndex = 0;
    unsigned total1s = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->frames->size(); i++) {
        scNode *node = this->frames->get(i);

        if(node->_time < min) {
            min = node->_time;
            if(node->reference == 0) {
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if(node->reference == 1) {
            ~node->reference;
            total1s++;
        }
    }

    if(total1s == this->frames->size()) {
        min = ULONG_MAX;
        for(int i = 0; i < this->frames->size(); i++) {
            scNode *node = this->frames->get(i);

            if(node->_time < min) {
                min = node->_time;
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return minIndex;
}
```

Comment: `this->frames->contains(new scNode(data));`  -- How do you plan to deallocate the memory allocated with `new` using this code?  This screams "memory leak" to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I suppose I could use `delete this->frames->get(i)` when I replace the node? Sorry, I'm still pretty new to C++

Comment: That won't work.  The pointer is lost, given the `contains` function.  Are you a Java programmer by any chance?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes -- it probably shows too :(. Can you elaborate on what you mean please?

Comment: When you call `new`, a pointer value is returned to you.  You need that value so that later on, you can call `delete` on that very value.  You don't save that `value` anywhere.  Stop or reduce using `new` in C++ programs -- the `new` in C++ is not the same thing as `new` in Java.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie duly noted

Comment: Also: `~node->reference;`  What are you trying to do here?  This is a mistake, unless you can clarify why you need to call the destructor explicitly.

Comment: Clerical error, my intention was to flip the bit

Comment: `throw new std::runtime_error("Bad reference to node");`  Throw by value and catch it by reference in C++.  You're creating a memory leak here also.  It should be `throw std::runtime_error("Bad reference to node");` -- My advice is to not write C++ code using Java as a model -- it will only get you deeper in trouble.

Comment: Duly noted again, I removed it after further contemplation earlier. Thanks for the advice though. Your comments are very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in following instruction:

```
this->frames = new Frames<scNode*>(this->page.frames, NULL);
```

So for `Frames<T>` T is scNode*, but I believe you intended to use just scNode. Currently you compare two pointers, but if you use `Frames<scNode>` then overloaded `operator ==` will be called for scNode.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two pointers. You need to compare their values instead.